# Prevent Forms Authentication from "spilling" between web applications on localhost

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm currently alternating between a few ASP.Net MVC project in my spare time and I've noticed that Forms authentication "spills over" between them. I.e. I do some work to project a and log in to test some functionality. Then I switch to project b and when I start that up I'm already signed in as the login from project a is still remembered by the browser and my local IIS Express.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change  `name` and `path` between different applications:

```
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
       protection="All"
       timeout="30"
       name="changethename" 
       path="/yourvirtual"
       requireSSL="false"
       slidingExpiration="true"
       defaultUrl="default.aspx"
       cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
       enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
```

[Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, changing the name worked like a charm. I tried to change just the path before asking here, but that didn't work. I'll add though (after trying) that it is not necessary to change the path attribute.

Comment: I only mention the path because web.configs inherit and if you have a root site, then virtual sites underneath, you may have a conflict.

Comment: @rickschott I've been struggling with this for an hour. Thanks!